# Magento RESTAPI restconnect working in localhost host but not working server

Tags: magento, jakarta-ee

I Using Magento 1.7.0.2 RestAPI on windows without problems.

On Linux everything was installed, but several urls or rewrite rules seem not to work.

For example http://example.com/magento/restconnect gives me always “404.”

This indicates, that the “RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]” does not work.

When I use “RewriteRule ^api api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]”, it works, but won’t help later in REST communication.

Another indication is: 
http://example.com/magento/admin/oAuth_authorize?oauth_token=… 
leads to “Whoops, our bad...” - so no response or bad url somehow.

Has anybody a hint? So somehow it is related to the REST functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 your server is nginx? i also have 404,i was so resolved,
 nginx conf configuration :
 server {
 listen 80;
 server_name mg.nieger.com;
 index index.html index.htm index.php;
 root /alidata/www/nieger;
 location ~ .*\.(php|php5)?$
 {
#fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
 }
location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
{
expires 30d;
}
location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
{
expires 1h;
}
location /api
{
rewrite ^/api/rest /api.php?type=rest last;
rewrite ^/api/v2_soap /api.php?type=v2_soap last;
rewrite ^/api/soap /api.php?type=soap last;
} 
#
include /alidata/server/nginx/conf/rewrite/magento.conf;
log_format nieger '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
access_log /alidata/log/nginx/access/default.log nieger;
}

i added the: 

**location /api 
{
rewrite ^/api/rest /api.php?type=rest last;
rewrite ^/api/v2_soap /api.php?type=v2_soap last;
rewrite ^/api/soap /api.php?type=soap last;
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. best answer in this link. linux server case sensitive

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/295638/